# Wordpress Swap Primary Menu from Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

**Scenario:**

I want to faciliate the user to choose from two different menus to be used as his/her primary menu.

I created two menus, and an Entry in both menus to switch to each other (Switch to B) (Switch to A).

The idea is that when a menu item is pressed, a wordpress function is called to switch the menu. Since I have already created the menus, they have specific IDs to choose from. All I want to hook specific function on clicking the (menu entries created in each menu) to swap the primary menu.

------------ **EDIT** ------------

**My Approach**

My Approach so far is as follows.

1. Created a template named `Menu_Switch` and created a wordpress page based on that template.
2. Called a function in that template.
3. I created the menu entry with that newly created page in both menus.

The function is as follows.

```
function switch_menu ( $args = '' ) {

    if( $args['theme_location'] == 'primary') {

        if ($args['menu'] == '45') {
            $args['menu'] = '65';
        }  else if ($args['menu'] == '65') {
            $args['menu'] = '45';
        }

        return $args;
    }

    $redirect = home_url();

}
```

AND then called the function in the template like this

```
<?php echo switch_menu(); ?>
```

**Question**

This code is not working as expected. Following is expected.

1. If the ID of `primary menu` is `45`, it should set it to `65` and vise-versa.
2. (Since the switch template is blank) The page should redirect either to previous page or the Home page.

Comment: Just to clarify your needs should that be ajax (menu change live)? or should that store that preference in some user-related settings to retrieve on each next visit?

Comment: I'm afraid that, without saving the settings, other pages will keep opening the default menu.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if that possible to do with way what you want - I mean changing location on fly, due it affects to **whole site for all users**.
You could to do it with next logic:

1. **display both menus on front**, one of them will be with `display: none`
2. when user selected another menu - **change some html class** (it's good - in body element), apply CSS to **hide one menu and display another**
3. store it's state in **cookie** for user will sees selected menu across all pages and when he back to site

**UPDATE**
I mean that you can to create two locations and display them next to each other on frontend - and in this case you can to **create two different menus** and to assign to different locations. Visually it **will be like two menus in one place**.

Please see example:
[image]

[image]

And using cookie and CSS you can to display one or another menu.

**UPDATE 2**
Full solution(**tested on real WordPress site**):

1. Create two locations for menus

```php
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'header_top_nav'        => __( 'Header Top Area', 'starter' ),
        'header_main_nav'       => __( 'Header Main Area', 'starter' )
    )
);
```

2. Create two menus, assign for locations above. Add to menus trigger buttons with html classes `js_btn_show_menu_a` and `js_btn_show_menu_b` which will be used for handle click in js
3. Display these menus on front:

```html
<nav class="menu_a">
   <?php
       wp_nav_menu(
           array(
               'theme_location' => 'header_top_nav'
           )
       );
   ?>
</nav>
<nav class="menu_b">
   <?php
       wp_nav_menu(
           array(
               'theme_location' => 'header_main_nav'
           )
       );
   ?>
</nav>
```

4. Add js for trigger **classes and set cookie**

```js
$( document ).on( 'click', '.js_btn_show_menu_a', function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( 'html' ).addClass( 'show_menu_a' ).removeClass( 'show_menu_b' );
    Cookies.set( 'menu', 'show_menu_a' );
})
$( document ).on( 'click', '.js_btn_show_menu_b', function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( 'html' ).addClass( 'show_menu_b' ).removeClass( 'show_menu_a' );
    Cookies.set( 'menu', 'show_menu_b' );
})
```

5. **Get cookie** on backend and setup it as html class on tag `<html>`

```php
$menu_cookie = htmlspecialchars( $_COOKIE['menu'] ) ? htmlspecialchars( $_COOKIE['menu'] ) : 'show_menu_a';
<html class="<?php echo esc_attr( $menu_cookie ); ?>">
```

6. **Add css** for display/hide menus based on css class

```css
.show_menu_a .menu_a {display: block;}
.show_menu_a .menu_b {display: none;}
.show_menu_b .menu_b {display: block;}
.show_menu_b .menu_a {display: none;}
```

Comment: Wordpress do not allow to set two menus for one place or make two primary menus at once.

Comment: Problem will remain the same, how would I run the function on the menu item to show / hide menus? If I get the function `code` run on a menu item, my approach is better to change the menu all together rather than playing it with css.

Comment: "my approach is better" - I don't think that it's solution. Change location works for ALL user.  

"how would I run the function on the menu item to show / hide menus" - what function do you mean? As I explained above - you can to output TWO menus, one will be with DISPLAY: NONE. Then when user select another view (I don't know how it should be implement in your interface) - user getting cooking and CURRENT MENU getting css DISPLAY: NONE, another MENU getting css DISPLAY: BLOCK.

Could you please explain what exactly for you unclear?

Comment: Please read the question again, `The menus are supposed to be changed by an entry in the menu itself`. Now even if I add two menus as you suggested, how would I `show / hide` from menu entry? If you suggest to write a function that set the css display:none to alternate menu, why not use the convenient method I am already using? The problem is `RUNNING THE FUNCTION / CODE FROM THE MENU`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understand you... you are writing 'I want to faciliate the user to choose from two different menus' - so do you want to display for `different users different menus`, or the same menu (i.e. one user can to change menu for all users)...?

Comment: Please see this image https://imgur.com/a/68xpO3S it explains using your own image.

Comment: Ok, so I got all correct. As I said - you can to use `js for to change class in html` and for to store this state - store this in `cookie`, so when user back/go to other page - he will sees selected menu. If you don't know how use js/cookie for that - pls let me know I'll add solution.

Comment: Yes, Please add your solution. Kindely do not forget that it is a wordpress based solution.

Comment: I've added full solution. It was done on real wordpress site. Simple 3 steps: set cookie, get cookie, add css. Really can't imagine what exactly was unclear, the solution is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for a filter where you can toggle your main menu.

If you will go through [wp_nav_menu()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L57) source code

There is a filter  `$args = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args', $args );` and this $args array structure is

```
$defaults = array(
        'menu'                 => '',
        'container'            => 'div',
        'container_class'      => '',
        'container_id'         => '',
        'container_aria_label' => '',
        'menu_class'           => 'menu',
        'menu_id'              => '',
        'echo'                 => true,
        'fallback_cb'          => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'               => '',
        'after'                => '',
        'link_before'          => '',
        'link_after'           => '',
        'items_wrap'           => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'item_spacing'         => 'preserve',
        'depth'                => 0,
        'walker'               => '',
        'theme_location'       => '',
    );
```

You can notice there is one key menu_id, if you can set that and apply this filter your menu will change based on the menu_id given.

something like

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', function(){
    $args['menu_id'] = <desired_menu_id>
    return $args;
});
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer but your code pointed out a mistake I was making. I'd try to develop an answer meanwhile.

Comment: @NaveedAbbas I have edited my answer, but if you have not solved the issue and need my help, please let me know.

Comment: I have updated my question, my objective is simple yet the scenario is a bit odd. I'd appreciate if you could test your codde in a working example. In current scenario, I also need redirection after swapping the menu.

Comment: @NaveedAbbas the issue with your code is, you have return statement before your redirect, so redirect will never happen, 2nd thing is the filter I have mentioned will help you only to set menu_id and other parameters related to menu, redirect should need a action hook, so both in one actions seems difficult, with menu change you can trigger a js event to redirect to home page. Today morning I have formatted my system, so still configuring will try to run my code, but it should work fine.